# tmux: ncurses apps are displayed wrong (with garbage and so on)

Tags: terminal, tmux, ncurses

I have ncurses apps (say, aptitude) working nice in plain xterm (or gnome-terminal, or any other terminal I've tried), but if I run it inside tmux session, screen isn't properly refreshed while I do some navigation through the menu.

Example screenshot: [image: aptitude qinside tmux]

(full resolution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UipyL.png)

The same happens with other ncurses apps inside tmux: say, [cgdb](https://github.com/cgdb/cgdb). And again, without tmux they work nice.

How to make it work correctly in tmux too?

(OS is Linux Mint 13, if that does matter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [tmux FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/FAQ):

> ```
> ******************************************************************************
> * PLEASE NOTE: most display problems are due to incorrect TERM! Before       *
> * reporting problems make SURE that TERM settings are correct inside and     *
> * outside tmux.                                                              *
> *                                                                            *
> * Inside tmux TERM must be "screen" or similar (such as "screen-256color").  *
> * Don't bother reporting problems where it isn't!
> ```

Comment: Thanks, as I just found out after your answer, my tmux config was actually correct (setting `TERM` to `screen-256color`), but for some reason this setting is overrided by one in the `~/.zshrc`, so `TERM` is finally set to `xterm-256color`. I'd be very glad if you take a look at my related question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139082/zsh-set-term-screen-256color-in-tmux-but-xterm-256color-without-tmux