# zsh: set TERM=screen-256color in tmux, but xterm-256color without tmux

Tags: zsh, tmux, xterm

I need my `$TERM` to be `xterm-256color` outside of tmux (in "plain" terminal with zsh), but `screen-256color` inside tmux.

First I tried:

- add `export TERM='xterm-256color'` to my `~/.zshrc`.
- add `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` to my `~/.tmux.conf`

Now, when I open terminal (say, xterm), `TERM` is `xterm-256color`, which is correct. But when I run tmux, `TERM` is again `xterm-256color`!

Then I tried to comment out line in my `~/.zshrc`. Now, when I open terminal, `TERM` is `xterm`, and when I run tmux, `TERM` is `screen-256color`. So it seems if I set `TERM` in the `.zshrc`, tmux firstly sets `TERM` to `screen-256color`, runs shell (which is zsh), and zsh reads `.zshrc` and resets `TERM` to `xterm-256color`.

So, how to make `TERM` to be `xterm-256color` in "plain" terminal, and `screen-256color` in tmux?

Comment: Set the TERM for xterm in the xterm configuration (X resources) and that for tmux in the tmux configuration. There's no reason you should do any of that in zsh.

Comment: Hmm, but I also use other terminal emulators: say, gnome-terminal and quake-style drop-down console "altyo" https://github.com/linvinus/AltYo , still can't find the way to set correct `TERM` in these terminals

Comment: Well those applications are responsible to set **their** TERM properly. For `gnome-terminal`, that should probably be `gnome-256color`... So it's those applications you need to configure properly, not `zsh`. The reason they use `xterm` is probably to avoid problems when sshing to machines that don't have the more specific terminfo entries. If you know you're only sshing to machines with an exhaustive terminfo database, then you can and should change that in the applications themselves.

Comment: And if you need to add a .zshrc kludge, IMO, that should be on machines that have incomplete terminfo databases (to replace xterm-256color with `xterm` if xterm-256color s not supported, though it would be even better to add those entries in our own ~/.terminfo database).

Comment: We should set term in the terminal emulator, not in `.zshrc`. It is not the correct way.

Comment: Note that `screen-256color` doesn't support italics, but `xterm-256color` does, so you won't be using the entire capabilities of your terminal. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The TERM environment variable should be set by the application that is acting as your terminal. This is the whole point of the thing: letting programs running inside them know what terminal is being used and hence what sort of features it supports.

Zsh is not a terminal. It is a shell. It might care what your TERM is set to if it wants to do special things, but it should not be responsible for *setting* it. Instead it is responsible for setting variables such as ZSH_VERSION which can be used by scripts or other child processes to understand what behavior to expect from their parent shell.

Instead, you need to check the configuration for whatever terminal application you are using and ask it to report itself properly. For example you can do this for xterm by adding this line to the `~/.Xdefaults` file it uses for configuration values:

```
xterm*termName: xterm-256color
```

It appears gnome-terminal does the idiotic thing of reading what your xterm configuration would be instead of having it's own. This might get you by in some cases but is should more properly be set to vte-256color. This appears to be a long standing gripe against it (and some other VTE based terminal emulators). A [common way](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/BackspaceDelete/system.html) to hack around this is exploit another value it does set:

```
if [ "$COLORTERM" = "gnome-terminal" ]; then
    export TERM=vte-256color
fi
```

But this brings you back around to your problem with tmux, so you would have to account for that by not resetting TERM if it is already something like "screen-256color" or "screen":

```
if [ "$COLORTERM" = "gnome-terminal" -a "$TERM" =~ xterm.* ]; then
    export TERM=vte-256color
fi
```

For other terminals you will need to lookup their proper configuration routines.

Comment: `zsh` is not responsible for setting `$SHELL`. `login` is responsible for setting it, and _you_ are responsible to change that to something else if you want to tell applications (`xterm`, `vi`...) which shell you want as your prefered shell. `zsh` is responsible for setting `$ZSH_VERSION` and a few documented special shell variables, but it doesn't touch `$SHELL`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That was sloppy of me, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks for this, it made me look for how `konsole` set TERM rather than putting it in my bashrc. Found it set in the profile's General tab, Environment, changed it from `xterm` to `xterm-256color`

Comment: worth noting that under my vanilla deb10 install GNOME Terminal reports `truecolor` instead of `gnome-terminal` for `$COLORTERM` and so the above detection mechanism may not work. XTERM does not appear to set this value at all, it may be valid to check for any value. this term type is partially discussed [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728#true-color-detection) possibly elsewhere: https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728#true-color-detection

Answer (score 12):

Inside your .zshrc, put

```
[[ -n $TMUX ]] && export TERM="xterm-256color"
```

And, inside your .tmux.conf

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Comment: Or

`[[ $TMUX != "" ]] && export TERM="screen-256color"`

This way zsh will set TERM only if called within a tmux session